# Create Object model with Dynamic Name and Properties JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, typescript, javascript-objects

I am new in javascript/typescript & figuring out a way to create a **dynamic named** object & obj **properties** in typescript based on the filter type like below

Number type Filter Properties :

```
 {
    "filterType": "",
    "type": "",
    "filter":'',
    "filterTo":'' 
 }
```

Text type Filter Properties :

```
{
   "filterType": "",
   "type": "",
   "filter": ""
}
```

Date type Filter Properties :

```
{
  "dateFrom": "",
  "dateTo": "",
  "filterType": "",
  "type": ""
}
```

Based on the filter type selected I want to create object with **particular filter type properties** like below

```
"filterModel": {
            "OriginDate": {            <--------------- this column name I will be getting at runtime which i want to be the object name
                "dateFrom": "2022-09-21 00:00:00",   >
                "dateTo": "2022-09-21 00:00:00",     >
                "filterType": "date",                > properties i want to set based on filter type
                "type": "inRange"                    >
            },
            "Score": {      <--------------- this column name I will be getting at runtime which i want to be the object name
                "filterType": "number",  >
                "type": "inRange",       >
                "filter": 0,             > properties i want to set based on filter type
                "filterTo": 90           >
            },
            "Title": {      <--------------- this column name I will be getting at runtime which i want to be the object name
                "filterType": "text",  >
                "type": "contains",    >  properties i want to set based on filter type
                "filter": "wire"       >
            }
}
```

Assuming the Inputs I will be getting for generating this object will be

```
  generateFilterModel(columnName : string ,filterType : any ,filtervalues: any[]) 
{

// logic  -> generating the object and adding it to filterModel {}

      
}
```

**For Removing all the filters I will be having a button to set** filterModel {} as empty

> Final Expected Output :

1. For **Input** ->  `this.generateFilterModel('OriginDate','Date',filtervalues[])` // (columnName, Filtertype , filtervalues)

**Output** :

```
"OriginDate": {
                "dateFrom": "2022-09-21 00:00:00",
                "dateTo": "2022-09-21 00:00:00",
                "filterType": "date",
                "type": "inRange"
            }
```

2. For **Input** ->  `this.generateFilterModel('Score','number',filtervalues[])` // (columnName, Filtertype , filtervalues)

**Output** :

```
"Score": {
            "filterType": "number",
            "type": "inRange",
            "filter": 0,
            "filterTo": 90
        }
```

3. For **Input** ->  `this.generateFilterModel('Title','text',filtervalues[])` // (columnName, Filtertype ,filtervalues)

**Output** :

```
"Title": {
            "filterType": "text",
            "type": "contains",
            "filter": "wire"
        }
```

**PLAYGROUND :-** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qizcir?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: A dynamic object: `this[name_of_variable]={}`, a dynamic propertie `obj[name_of_variable]=value` a dynamic property inside an object: `obj={[name_of_variable]:value}`

Comment: Thanks for comment @Eliseo can you please elaborate bit clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

model

```
export interface filterModel {
  OriginDate?: OriginDate;
  Score?: Score;
  Title?: Title;
}

export interface OriginDate {
  dateFrom: string;
  dateTo: string;
  filterType: string;
  type: string;
}

export interface Score {
  filterType: string;
  type: string;
  filter: number;
  filterTo: number;
}

export interface Title {
  filterType: string;
  type: string;
  filter: string;
}
```

main file

```
const originalObj = {
  filterModel: {},
};
function generateFilterModel(
  columnName: string,
  filterType: any,
  filtervalues: OriginDate | Score | Title
) {
  const createObj = {
    [columnName]: filtervalues,
  };
  Object.assign(originalObj['filterModel'], createObj);
  console.log(originalObj);
}

const originDateObj = {
  dateFrom: '2022-09-21 00:00:00',
  dateTo: '2022-09-21 00:00:00',
  filterType: 'date',
  type: 'inRange',
};
generateFilterModel('OriginDate', 'Date', originDateObj);

const scoreObj = {
  filterType: 'number',
  type: 'inRange',
  filter: 0,
  filterTo: 90,
};
generateFilterModel('Score', 'number', scoreObj);

const titleObj = {
  filterType: 'text',
  type: 'contains',
  filter: 'wire',
};
generateFilterModel('Title', 'text', titleObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Basic way:**

You should defined the interfaces of the filters first:

```js
type FilterType = "number" | "text" | "date"

interface FilterBase {
  filterType: FilterType
  type: string
}

interface NumberFilter extends FilterBase {
  filterType: "number"
  filter: string
  filterTo: string
}

interface TextFilter extends FilterBase {
  filterType: "text"
  filter: string
}

interface DateFilter extends FilterBase {
  filterType: "date"
  dateFrom: ""
  dateTo: ""
}

type Filter = NumberFilter | TextFilter | DateFilter
```

then apply to your function

```js
function generateFilterModel(columnName: string, filterType: FilterType, filtervalues: any[]): Record<string, Filter> {
  // do what you want here
}
```

in this case, the return type will become `Record<string, Filter>` which is wide but fit most of the usage already.

**Some advanced ways:**

if the type need to be more correct like `columnName` must be known in the type, it can be:

```js
function generateFilterModel<T extends string>(columnName: T, filterType: FilterType, filtervalues: any[]): Record<T, Filter> {
  // do what you want here
}
```

moreover, if the type of `Filter` must be more accurate, you will need do defined a map first:

```js
interface FilterMap {
  number: NumberFilter
  text: TextFilter
  date: DateFilter
}
```

and the function will be:

```js
function generateFilterModel<T extends string, U extends FilterType>(columnName: T, filterType: U, filtervalues: any[]): Record<T, FilterMap[U]> {
  // do what you want here
}
```

Comment: how will be the return object created? can you provide some sudo code

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qizcir?file=src/app/app.component.html